# Roles Resources | What is "My Account" for

Tags: magento2, user-roles

I found this in the role resources but am not sure what it is responsible for. Enabling and disabling this seems to make no difference. Can someone shine some light on it?

**Magento ver. 2.1.8**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one related to My account section, which is in upper right corner. Please check below image

[image]